# JSON.parse vs json_decode

Tags: php, json

I am currently learning php as I build a database website. I am passing information between functions using JSON objects. I have come across two different functions JSON.parse and json_decode. Please can someone explain to me what the difference is and when I should be using each of them.

Many thanks

Comment: PHP doesn't have a function called `JSON.parse`, but javascript does.

Comment: Ahhh...that's where Im getting confused. Yes I have used a few bits of javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The language!

There is no function called `JSON.parse` in PHP. Also PHP does not have this syntax at all.This is a method of Javascript.

`json_decode()` **is** an standard function of PHP and parses JSON to PHP Objects, arrays, etc.

You can see PHP official documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php) for more about `json_decode`

Answer (score 1):

json_decode() is a php function which converts json data into php objects.
json.parse() is a function in javascript which converts json data in javascript objects.